# How to not supply all the default arguments when calling Python function?

Tags: python

Let's say I have this function code:

```
def dosomething(thing1, thing2='hello', thing3='world'):
    print(thing1)
    print(thing2)
    print(thing3)
```

When calling it, I would like to be able to specify what `thing3` is, but without having to say what `thing2` is. (The code below is how I thought it might work...)

```
dosomething("This says 'hello fail!'", , 'fail!')
```

and it would say:

```
This says 'hello fail!'
hello
fail!
```

So is there a way to do it like that, or would I have to specify `thing2` every time I wanted to say what `thing3` was?

Comment: So you have a function where arguments `thing2,3` are named (kwarg) arguments. And the way you attempted to do this in your code was by trying to pass them by positional association, but omitting thing2; however "This...", , "fail!" is a syntax error, you can't have two commas after each other and no value. So you need named association `(...thing3=='fail!')`.

Comment: Yes, that's the accepted answer (from 12 years ago)!

Comment: @hiftanotiks: sure, I'm trying to help OP and other readers phrase their question in more Pythonic terms so it gets indexed better. Also, the OP never states what the actual symptom is, but having two back-to-back commas is a syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use keyword arguments

```
dosomething("This says 'hello fail!'", thing3='fail!')
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can:

```
dosomething("This says 'hello fail!'", thing3 = 'fail!')
```